# Richfaces dataTable inside hidden popupPanel bad rendering

Tags: internet-explorer, jsf, richfaces

I have rich:popupPanel which contains rich:dataTable. Popup panel is hidden until button is pressed, but skeleton of datatable is shown on page(popupPanel is stil hidden). Skeleton(grid) disapears only after popupPanel is shown for the first time.
This only happens in IE7 which is nonfunctional requirement from other party.

If someone had similar issue i'd be much obliged?

Comment: There is [a whole bunch of problems](https://www.google.com/search?q=richfaces+popuppanel+ie7&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&client=firefox-a#hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=gSC&rls=org.mozilla:en-US%3Aofficial&sclient=psy-ab&q=datatable+richfaces+popuppanel+ie7&oq=datatable+richfaces+popuppanel+ie7&gs_l=serp.3...41508.48702.0.49089.18.14.4.0.0.3.368.2567.1j9j2j2.14.0...0.0...1c.1.7.psy-ab.TIaeG7uQ98U&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_qf.&bvm=bv.44158598,d.dmg&fp=633ecc7090072a73&biw=1280&bih=593) with popups in IE7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found out a workaround. (*note target browser*)

Mesh(grid/skeleton) of table is not shown when popupPanel is hidden only when table has style attribute:

```
style="border-collapse:separate"
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your workaround!

However, the table afterwards has some gaps between the table cells.

In order to get the same appearance of the table back, you may also want to use a simple jQuery function to remove the style when the popup is first shown:

```
<a4j:commandButton id="showPopupButton" value="Show Details" render="detailsPopup"
limitRender="true" 
oncomplete="#{rich:jQuery('detailsPopupDataTable')}.css('border-collapse','');
#{rich:component('detailsPopup')}.show(); return true;"/>
```

Comment: Yeah, without StackOverflow we would be screwed with problems like that. Would Upvote you too, but I dont have enough reputation yet :)